# How to modify treeBuilder.Dot to generate LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN in custom function generator for NHibernate?

Tags: sql-server, linq, nhibernate, .net-4.5, linq-to-nhibernate

Im trying to extend LINQ to NHibernate provider for my custom function. The problem that I found is that, whenever I try to access a FK from my entity, it generates a "INNER JOIN" statement, but I want to have a LEFT JOIN, so I have all the "DistributorAnswers" where the "Distributor" FK is null. 
Here's the BuildHql:

```
public override HqlTreeNode BuildHql(MethodInfo method, Expression targetObject,
            ReadOnlyCollection<Expression> arguments,
            HqlTreeBuilder treeBuilder, IHqlExpressionVisitor visitor)
        {
            var targetNode = visitor.Visit(targetObject).AsExpression();
            return treeBuilder.Dot(targetNode, treeBuilder.Ident(nameof(DistributorAnswer.Distributor)));
        }
```

The generated SQL query currently uses an INNER JOIN, and I need to modify it to use a LEFT JOIN instead.
Here's the query output that I found with **SQL Server Profiler**

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'select TOP (@p0)
 ...
from [DistributorAnswer] distributo0_ 
inner join [Distributor] distributo1_ on distributo0_.Distributor_id=distributo1_.Id
```

And here's the LINQ that i'm trying to run with my custom function:

```
Session.Query<DistributorAnswer>()
                .Select(x => x.MyCustomMethod())
                .Take(10)
                .ToList();
```

The problem I am facing is that I don't know how to modify the treeBuilder.Dot method to generate the desired LEFT JOIN. I have examined the available methods and properties in the HqlTreeBuilder class, but I couldn't find a direct way to specify the join type.

I tried to use treeBuilder.LeftJoin but I cannot find any documentation about this and I really don't understand how it works.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: So what's the definition for `DistributorAnswer`? Sounds like the `Distributor` FK is specified as a not-nullable in C#.

Comment: DistributorAnswer has the property with the attribute `[CanBeNull]` and in the database there's registers with the Distributor_Id as null.
Here's how i define it inside `DistributorAnswer`
`[CanBeNull] public virtual Distributor Distributor { get; set; }`